# jpeg to bmp with 300x300 resolution outputs distorted grayscale image

Tags: c, image, bitmap, jpeg, libjpeg

I am using libjpeg on a Ubuntu 14.04 environment to decompress my JPEG image and write it to a BMP file. However, if I have a colored JPEG image with 300x300 resolution(2550x4206 pixels), the output BMP file is in grayscale and image seems dull. Other JPEG images with resolution  200x200, 400x400 and 600x600 will output the correct BMP image. Need your advice on this. Please help. Thank you.

link to JPEG image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ob0t07z5xEdmtVVWRicUQ5SGs/view?usp=sharing

Preview for BMP is not available. Download and view the image in Ubuntu or a Linux environment system. I have no idea why it doesn't display the image in Google or even in Windows.

link to output BMP image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ob0t07z5xEZTMycVRVX3Vscnc/view?usp=sharing

Code snippet writing decompressed JPEG image to BMP file:

```
struct jpeg_decompress_struct cinfo;
unsigned int bytesPerRow = cinfo.output_width * cinfo.num_components;
unsigned int colColor;
FILE *bmpFile = NULL;

while (cinfo.output_scanline < cinfo.image_height) {

    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];
    row_pointer[0] = raw_image
            + cinfo.output_scanline * bytesPerRow;
    jpeg_read_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);
    for (colColor = 0; colColor < cinfo.image_width; colColor++) {

        /* BMP scanlines should be aligned at 4-byte boundary */

    }

    /* write each row to bmp file */
    fwrite(row_pointer[0], 1, bytesPerRow, bmpFile);
}
```

BMP FILE: (bit fields are set byte by byte)

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned int img_bits_per_pixel;
    unsigned int img_scansize;
    unsigned int img_width;
    unsigned int img_height;
} Image_Information;

Image_Information *image_info;
image_info = (Image_Information *) malloc(sizeof(Image_Information));

image_info->img_height = cinfo.image_height;
image_info->img_width = cinfo.image_width;
image_info->img_scansize = ((image_info->img_width * 24 + 31) & ~31) / 8;

BITMAPFILEHEADER:
bfType = "BM";
bfSize = sizeof(BITMAPFILEHEADER) + sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) + image_info->img_scansize * image_info->img_height;
bfReserved1 = 0;    
bfReserved2 = 0;
bfOffBits = 54;

BITMAPINFOHEADER:
biSize  = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); 
biWidth = image_info->img_width;
biHeight = image_info->img_heigh;
biPlanes = 1;
biBitCount = 24;
biCompression = 0;
biSizeImage = 0;
biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
biClrUsed = 0;
biClrImportant = 0;
```

Comment: the link to the output image fails, even with using one of the google pixel editors  Please re-post the image or correct the link

Comment: void_ptr added code snippet for writing decompressed JPEG to BMP file. @user3629249 Download the file and try to view the file in Ubuntu or a Linux environment. I have no idea why it doesn't display the image in Google or even in Windows :(

Comment: a .bmp file fields must be in the correct 'endian' format.  This usually means that the fields must be set byte by byte.   The width of a row must be a multiple of 4 bytes long.  Assuming the image is being set to: 2550 pixels at 24 bits (3 bytes) per pixel, the resulting row width will not be a multiple of 4. so the `for( iCount -...) loop needs to be made smarter to allow for the trailing padding characters (if any) that need to be at the end of each row

Comment: Yes, I set the .bmp file fields byte by byte. Do I just add 1 byte at the end of each row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got the answer from @user3629249. Thank you.
I just added 2 bytes of padding at the end of each row only if resolution is 300x300

```
padding = 0;
fwrite(&padding, 2, 1, bmpFile);
```